# Is there a list of Jboss port numbers that a JBoss instance uses?

Tags: jboss, port, jboss5.x

I have to configure an instance of Jboss 5.1.0 to use a different port number (i.e. 8480). To do this i made the following changes to the bindings-jboss-beans.xml.

```
<parameter>
            <set>
               <inject bean="PortsDefaultBindings"/>
               <inject bean="Ports01Bindings"/>
               <inject bean="Ports02Bindings"/>
               <inject bean="Ports03Bindings"/>
               <inject bean="Ports04Bindings"/>
            </set>
         </parameter>

<bean name="Ports04Bindings" class="org.jboss.services.binding.impl.ServiceBindingSet">
      <constructor>
         <!--  The name of the set -->
         <parameter>ports-04</parameter>
         <!-- Default host name -->
         <parameter>${jboss.bind.address}</parameter>
         <!-- The port offset -->
         <parameter>400</parameter>
         <!-- Set of bindings to which the "offset by X" approach can't be applied -->
         <parameter><null/></parameter>
      </constructor>
   </bean>
```

The change works fine in that i can access my application using the URL `http://localhost:8480/XYZApp.`

Now to be able to do the deployment, i have to inform the infrastructure people all the port numbers that the application will use. 
I know that we will be using 8480 but how would i know all the other port numbers that Jboss will use for this instance based on an offset of 400?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JBoss listens to many ports for each of its services respectively, but you shouldn't need to open all those ports if your applications don't make use of the services related to these ports. For example if no external applications will use the Naming Service you shouldn't need to open the port 1099 (1499 in your case).

Anyway, if you need a list of all the ports from where Jboss listens, you can check the bean with name="StandardBindings" in the file conf/bindingservice.beans/META-INF/bindings-jboss-beans.xml. Those are the standard ports, so if you have defined an offset (in your case 400) you'll have to add it to the respective port to get the ports used by your JBoss instance.

Comment: Yes this is the file i used to determine the list of ports. Thanks